# Single table inheritance and one-to-many relation - how to avoid overhead

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, single-table-inheritance

I am building a survey builder where each question be textfield, textarea, dropdown, checkboxes, etc - just a normal query builder

I was thinking about making a base question class with main functionality and then extend it to implement all kinds of questions i need.

So questions would use a single table inheritance in doctrine and would work just fine.

The problem arises when we need to add options entities to dropdown or radio question as one-to-many relation. It is clearly stated in the Doctrine docs that we should only apply One-To-Many to the leafs. while in this situation, the Option entity will be mapped to an intermediate class QuestionListBase which will be then extended by QuestionDropdown, QuestionCheckboxes, etc.. Plus i may need to create new classes from QuestionDropdown, so it's basically not an option.

Is it at all possible to implement such functionality with Docrine and avoid performance issues?

Comment: was actually thinking about creating just one QuestionEntity class, which has every field i need, and then create a wrapper base class which would take QuestionEntity in contructor and then copy the basic question functionality like get/setTitle, etc. But i have a feeling that there will be problems with persisting questionentity in the database

Comment: I think you could use one Question entity which is as always a pure data layer. Then you could consider to use an Interface instead of a baseclass and a new class for every type of question that implements the Interface.